# Binomial series and relationship between two consecutive terms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-theorem

I am reading a French book called Traite du calcul differentiel et integral, vol 1. He set out to explain the binomial series and write things as followed:

> The analytic expression is put in the form:$(1-x)^m=1+\dfrac{m}{1}x+\dfrac{m(m+1)}{1\cdot2}x^2+\dfrac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}x^3....+\dfrac{m(m-1)...(m-n+2)}{1\cdot2...\cdot(n-1)}x^{n-1}+\dfrac{m(m-1)...(m-n+1)}{1\cdot2...n}x^n+etc....$
>
> It is shown that the relationship between any two consecutive terms is $\dfrac{m-n+1}{n}$

I don't understand how did he derive the relationship between each two terms as $\dfrac{m-n+1}{n}$. Can you help me to explicate this matter better?

Comment: Get a common denominator?

Comment: @ChrisCuster, can you be more specific?

Comment: It looks like you lost a minus sign.  BTW this is on display in _Pascal's Triangle_.  I guess you could prove it by induction.  Or just note ${m\choose n}+{m\choose n+1}={m+1\choose n+1}$.  This is called Pascal's identity.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: I check the book and it doesn't have any minus sign. Maybe it is a typo from the book?

Comment: $\dfrac{m-n+1}n$ appears to be the _ratio_ of consecutive terms, actually.

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo.

Comment: @ChrisCuster It is written originally in French as followed: faire voir que le rapport entre deux termes consecutifs quelconques est $\dfrac{m-n+1}{n}x$. I translate "rapport" as relationship, not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Apparently the "ratio" is intended.

Comment: @JamesWarthington Are you sure you copied the sign in $(1-x)^m$ right? Wouldn't it be $(1+x)^m$? See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series; or they are taking about negative binomial series for $(1-x)^{-m}$, where the first $4$ terms match?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

So, consecutive terms are $m\choose {n-1}$ and $m\choose n$.  Now divide the second by the first.

Remember ${m\choose n}=\dfrac{m!}{(m-n)!n!}$.

Comment: It's upside down.  And replace $n+1$ by $n$.

Comment: Ok I got this thank you, I mixed up $n-1$ and $n+1$. It is supposed to be $\dfrac{m!}{(m-n)!n!}\cdot\dfrac{[m-(n-1)!](n-1)!}{m!}$, which is finally $\dfrac{m+1-n}{n}$

Comment: You got it. Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Haven't it been that you detect the term "ratio", I would not be able to grasp what Lacroix suppose to mean.

Comment: My pleasure James.

Answer (score 0):

A minus sign is missing. If you write out the last coefficient in a bit more detail, it is   m(m-1)...(m-n+2)(m-n+1)/(1.2. ... .(n-1)n), so everything except (m-n+1)/n cancels out, except for the missing minus sign.